# Generating Basin Layer Using Hydrology Tool gives ERROR 010067

Tags: arcgis-desktop, basin, hydrology-toolset, error-010067, error-010005

I am new to the hydrology tool in ArcGIS Desktop and I have been trying to generate basin layer from flow direction layer for a very large area using the Aster dataset. Every time I run the process, it takes around 4 hours to complete and then results in the following two errors.

> ERROR:010067: ERROR IN EXECUTING GRID EXPRESSION
>
> ERROR: 010005: UNABLE TO ALLOCATE MEMORY.

```
# Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "flowdirnull.tif"
arcpy.gp.Basin_sa("flowdirnull.tif", "G:/ASTER NORTHEAST ARCGIS/basinull.tif")
```

Comment: "When working with a file-based raster dataset, the value for the input is set to a negative integer (such as -32767)" >> set your values to null https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014968

Comment: See if setting parallel processing factor in environment settings helps. Read help first.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what the actual command parameters were (Geoprocessing -> Results -> Copy as Python snippet)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, please check I have added the Python snippet to my query.

Answer (score 1):

Error 010005 is saying is that your file is too big to handle, and at some point ArcGIS ran out of memory. Some general ways one can deal with too large of rasters are:

1. Parallel processing (see @FelixIP's comment above)
2. Breaking your processing down into subsections (I don't know enough about hydrology to know if this makes sense for your particular type of analysis). [One way to do this is via tiles](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/supplement/tiled-processing-of-large-datasets.htm).
3. Changing the resolution of your data to a coarser resolution via resampling

You might also want to take a look at some of these other related posts having to do with Error 01005 ([Reclassification and 01005](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304661/using-reclass-in-arcpy-error-010005-unable-to-allocate-memory) and [Unable to allocate memory](https://community.esri.com/thread/205709-unable-to-allocate-memory-bug)), as well as @Mapperz suggestion in the comments of an [Error 010067 posting](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014968).